# ImportError: cannot import name make_pipeline

Tags: windows, python-2.7, scikit-learn, anaconda

I keep getting and error when trying to test machine learning code on Python http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection_pipeline.html#example-feature-selection-pipeline-py.

I'm using windows 8.1.  I've downloaded spyder and anaconda with python version 2.7.

I can run other examples fine, but whenever something uses pipe I get the error:

ImportError: cannot import name make_pipeline.

I'm using the latest development version of scikit-learn.

Comment: which version of  scikit-learn are you using?

Comment: When you say you are using the latest development version, are you making sure you are actually importing this version, not the anaconda one? You can do "import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version, sklearn.__path)" to find out. make_pipeline was included in 0.15 iirc.